Elliptic Curves over finite field which contains Klein's-4 Group as a subgroup
So here's my question which I got from a practice problem set on Elliptic Curves.

Let $E:y^2=x^3+ax+b$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_p$ ( $p$ is prime $>3$)
For which polynomial $x^3+ax+b$ does $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ contain Klein's-4 group as a subgroup?

My approach: I can figure out such curves specifically, like I can take $E:y^2=x^3-x$ over $\mathbb{F}_5$. We can easily verify that $E(\mathbb{F}_5) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2\bigoplus\mathbb{Z}_4$, which indeed contains Klein's-4 Group as it's subgroup. But how to find all such Elliptic Curve equation in general that I don't know. Any help will be appreciated.

There is only one point at infinity on the curve, namely the point $(0,1,0)$ which serves as the identity element for the group of rational points.  All other points are finite and may be expressed as $(x,y,1)$ (or simply $(x,y)$).  Also, the inverse of such a point $P \equiv (x,y)$ is the point
$-P\equiv (x, -y)$, and hence a point $P$ of order two is one for which $(x, y) = (x, -y)$ (i.e. one for which $y = 0$ or, in other words, the $x$-coordinate of the point is a root of the polynomial $x^3 + ax + b$.  In order for the point to be rational, this root should belong to the ground field.  Thus there are at most three rational points of order two on the curve (stemming from whether the polynomial $x^3 + ax + b$ has either no root, one single root, or three distinct roots, over the ground field). Thus the elliptic curve has a Klein-4 subgroup in its group of rational points precisely when the polynomial $x^3 + ax + b$ splits into three distinct linear factors over the ground field (or field of definition of the curve).

ground field means any given field ?

@Guruprasad ground field means field of definition of the curve (the field in which the coefficients $a, b$ of the polynomial $x^3 + ax+ b$ is defined to belong).

Really I don't know, I readed many Books related to Elliptic Curves but many authours don't Use this word

@Guruprasad different books use different terminology -- it basically refers to the field of definition of the curve. Maybe it is not a commonly used terminology.

Thank You for your time to comment.

Hint. If I'm not mistaken, for an elliptic curve in the form $y^2=x^3+ax+b$
then $−(x,y)=(x,−y).$
Hence if a point $P=(x,y)$ satisfies $2P=0$, then $y=0$
or $y=\infty$.
Note that you need to check in which case you have at least two distinct points of order $2$ (they will generate a Klein subgroup)
.

Since the equation $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$ defines an elliptic curve, it is implicit (by definition) that the polynomial $x^3 + ax + b$ has three distinct roots $x_1, x_2, x_3$.  Each of these roots gives rise to a point $(x_i, 0)$ of order 2 (and since there are three of them, we have at least two distinct points of order $2$), so the elliptic curve in question always contains a Klein-4 subgroup in its group of rational points.

Assuming the characteristic of the field of definition is not equal to $2$ or $3$, if the polynomial $x^3 + ax + b$ did not have distinct roots, it would not define an elliptic curve (since in this case the curve would be singular).

@AnuradhaN. The polynomial $x^3 + ax + b$ will have three distinct roots, but these might not live over the ground field. In the OP's example, the polynomial $x^3 - x$ over $\mathbb{F}_5$ does indeed have all three roots, namely 0,1, and 4. This is why $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4$ does have exactly three elements of order 2. This is not always true however. You can consider the polynomial $x^3 - 1$ over $\mathbb{F}_5$ which does have distinct roots, but only one of these roots actually lives in $\mathbb{F}_5$ so there is only one point of order two in this case.

@EricZhu  Yes, I stand corrected.  Since any point of order two stems from the roots of the polynomial $x^3 + ax + b$ over the ground field, hence the curve contains a Klein-4 subgroup in its group of rational points only if this polynomial splits into linear factors over the ground field.
